# Implemating git push and pull with simple-git package in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, git, github

I am currently developing an online code editor. One of the features of the app is cloning or pulling a remote repository and the user also can push his project to the remote repository. Because the app has Github Oauth, with the token I can access private repos too. The cloning of any repo works perfectly. **If I clone a repo first the pull and push work perfect too, but if I don't clone, they don't work at all.** I have searched a lot on the internet, but I haven't found good examples so I can learn how to properly use this simple-git package.

**Does anyone have implemented something similar or have worked with this package again and can share a snippet of code with implementing these 3 functionalities?**

These are the functions that I have implemented so far.

```
//if the repo folder that the user selected exists then pull the changes from the remote else it 
//clones the remote

  function repo (req,res){

    fs.exists(path.join(__dirname,currentpath,repo_fname),async exists => {
        if(exists){
            //git pull here
            const git = simpleGit({ baseDir: path.join(__dirname,currentpath,repo_fname) });

            User.findOne({git_user: req.body.git_username})
            .exec(async(error , user) => {
                await git.addConfig('user.email',user.git_email);
                await git.addConfig('user.name',user.git_user);
            })

            git.addRemote(req.body.username, repolink);
            await git.add('./*');
           
            await git.commit("Updated"+ new Date());
            
            await git.pull(req.body.username, req.body.branch)
            .then(()=>{
                console.log('Pulling Repo finished\n');
                res.send({mess: "ok"});
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error('failed: ', err);
                res.send({err : "The pulling of the repo failed.Please try again."});});

        }else{
             //git clone here
            try{
                fs.mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname,currentpath,repo_fname),{recursive:true});
                const git = simpleGit({ baseDir: path.join(__dirname,currentpath,repo_fname) });
                const  options = ["--single-branch", "--branch" , req.body.branch,'--depth', '1'];
                git.clone(repolink, path.join(__dirname,currentpath,repo_fname),options)
                .then(() => {
                  console.log('Cloning Repo finished\n');
                  res.send({mess: "ok"});
                 })
                .catch((err) => {
                console.error('failed: ', err);
                res.send({err : "The cloning of the repo failed.Please try again."});});
               
            }catch{
                let err= "Error with creating folder"+ folderpath;
                console.log(err);
                res.send({err: err});
            }   
        }
      });}
```

```
//pushes the  local repo to the remote
async funcion pushrepo (req,res){  
     
    const git = simpleGit({ baseDir: path.join(__dirname,currentpath) });

    User.findOne({git_user: req.body.git_username})
    .exec(async(error , user) => {
        awaitgit.addConfig('user.email',user.git_email);
        await git.addConfig('user.name',user.git_user);

        await git.add('./*');
        await git.commit(req.body.commit_msg);
        git.addRemote(req.body.username, req.body.repolink);

        await git.push(req.body.username, req.body.branch,["--set-upstream","--force"])
        .then(()=>{
            console.log('Pushing to Repo finished\n');
            res.send({mess: "ok"});
            
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('failed: ', err);
            res.send({err : "The push to the repo failed.Please try again."});
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Push and pull operations (don't use pull from programs!) mean "do something with an existing repository": the repository must exist! Clone means "make a new, totally empty repository, then populate it from some existing repository": the repository must not yet exist. Of course you must *create* the repository before fetching or pushing (use fetch, not pull).

Comment: Thank you, your comment help me to solve the problem. What I had to do is to check if the repo existed and if it didn't I had to git.init() and add the remote repo. After I did that everything worked fine.